# displaying the file data in correct format

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

In views.py

```
def showfiledata(request):  
with open("/home/tazim/webexample/tmp.txt") as f:  
     read_data = f.read()  
f.closed  
return_dict = {'filedata':read_data}  
json = simplejson.dumps(return_dict)  
return HttpResponse(json,mimetype="application/json")
```

In the template:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquerycall/"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function()  
    {  
         $("button").click(function()  
         {

              $.ajax({  
                       type:"POST",  
                       url:"/showfiledata/",  
                       datatype:"json",  
                       success:function(data)  
                               {  
                                  var s = data.filedata;  
                                  $("#someid").html(s);  
                               }  


                    });  
         });  

    });  
</script>    
</head>  
<body>  
<form method="post">  
<button type="button">Click Me< /button>  
<div id="someid">< /div>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

I am suppose to display file line by line .
But, right now the lines get displayed withoout any linebreaks.

Comment: isn't this a repetition - in the other thread you said nothing is displayed; now it's about line breaks?

Comment: Yes, if you are now successfully showing data, please mark the other question as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#someid").html(s.join("<br/>"));
```